# docker-machine Failure to join workers

Tags: docker

I am trying to run

```
docker-machine ssh myvm2 "docker swarm join --token SwMTKN-1-2yn45nfxrrw2lnmpipxgq3p9c1xj11Svt5931xz166m3tqj6cv-61uwpwyg9u3segs8slt5p466l 192.168.161.163:2376"
```

Join mymv2 as a worker to the cluster, But got this error

```
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all Subconns are in TransientFailure,
latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: remote error: tls: bad certificate"
exit status 1
```

Excuse me, how can I solve this error?

Comment: Excuse me, please provide code's not screenshots. :-)

Comment: As @Sinto has pointed out, it's better to post text instead of screenshots. If you are on a situation that you can't mark the console text and then copy it, please OCR your screenshots and then paste the text here. I did it for you now, keep it in mind for the next time. There are plenty of online OCR tools, I used [www.i2ocr.com/](http://www.i2ocr.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Change the port to 2377 in --advertise-addr while creating swarm and join the other managers and workers using the same port to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you entered something like the following to initiate your swarm.

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.161.163:2376
```

change it to

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.161.163:2377
```

From Docker

> Always run docker swarm init and docker swarm join with port 2377 (the
>   swarm management port), or no port at all and let it take the default.
>
> The machine IP addresses returned by `docker-machine ls` include port
>   2376, which is the Docker daemon port. Do not use this port or you may
>   experience errors.

https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/